# Windows stopped closing TCP connections on process termination

Tags: networking, tcp

It used to be simple - kill a program and the ports got reset so I can put up a new listen. That stopped happening as of, I think 1809. Just tried 1903 and still a problem.

Has something changed? I can't even kill the process holding the connection even if the process is "nonexistent". But I do get the port freed if I log off.

Any idea what happened to cleaning up TCP connections?

Comment: What state are the sockets reported in, after you kill the process? Are they perhaps in TIME_WAIT state after this happens?

Comment: It never times out. 

I captured images from TCPView but I don't know how to include them here.

(damn -- newline posts)

After I stopped the program I looked again at TCPView and it is still showing them connected to the same PID even though there is no longer that PID. The connections are still shown as established.